# Making changes global variables from within a function

Tags: python, tkinter

Background:
My goal is to make a timer to track and time pages sent after hours at work. I'll paste the raw page text into a box, press a button, and it will parse this to grab the ticket, title, analyst and their number, as well as starting a timer to track when to repage/escalate. The idea was to use grid and 5 sets of variables to create 5 possible rows to throw ticket information into at one time, preferable only using one entry box/button combo that chooses the first available row.

I'm currently stuck on how to set the string variables (Or even access the contents of the text box for the unparsed information) to display the ticket info from within the function that will be used for the button press. I'm getting an undefined error when referencing either from within the function, even when declaring them globally (which I'm not even 100% on if/how that works with a tkinter widget and using .get()?).

I have a feeling I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong but I'm having a a lot of trouble wrapping my head around how else I could accomplish this.

Main App:

```
from tkinter import *
from newPageEntry import *

#Create window
master = Tk()
master.title('SD Page Time')
master.configure(bg='White')

#Page entry text box setup
newPageTextBox = Entry(master)
newPageTextBox.grid(row=6, column=6)

#page entry button
newPageButton1 = Button(master, text="New Page", width=10, command=newPageEntry(newPageTextBox.get())).grid(row=6, column=7)

#Grid Variables Setup
ticketNumberString1 = StringVar()
analystNameString1 = StringVar()
analystPhoneString1 = StringVar()
ticketTitleString1 = StringVar()

ticketNumberString2 = StringVar()
analystNameString2 = StringVar()
analystPhoneString2 = StringVar()
ticketTitleString2 = StringVar()

ticketNumberString3 = StringVar()
analystNameString3 = StringVar()
analystPhoneString3 = StringVar()
ticketTitleString3 = StringVar()

ticketNumberString4 = StringVar()
analystNameString4 = StringVar()
analystPhoneString4 = StringVar()
ticketTitleString4 = StringVar()

ticketNumberString5 = StringVar()
analystNameString5 = StringVar()
analystPhoneString5 = StringVar()
ticketTitleString5 = StringVar()
```

New page module:

```
from telalertParse import *
# import timer once made

#gets telalert page raw text from text box, enters it into parser. 
#inserts [ticketNumber, analystName, analystNumber, title] into the first available row, clears box
def newPageEntry(telalertPage):
    global newPageTextBox
    newPageTextBox.delete(0, END)
    telalertParseReturn = telalertParse(telalertPage)

    ticketNumber = telalertParseReturn[0]
    analystName = telalertParseReturn[1]
    analystNumber = telalertParseReturn[2]
    title = telalertParseReturn[3]

    if ticketNumberString1.get() != '':
        ticketNumberString1.set(ticketNumber)
        analystNameString1.set(analystName)
        analystPhoneString1.set(analystNumber)
        ticketTitleString1.set(title)
        #Start Timer

    elif ticketNumberString2.get() != '':
        ticketNumberString2.set(ticketNumber)
        analystNameString2.set(analystName)
        analystPhoneString2.set(analystNumber)
        ticketTitleString2.set(title)
        #Start Timer

    elif ticketNumberString3.get() != '':
        ticketNumberString3.set(ticketNumber)
        analystNameString3.set(analystName)
        analystPhoneString3.set(analystNumber)
        ticketTitleString3.set(title)
        #Start Timer

    elif ticketNumberString4.get() != '':
        ticketNumberString4.set(ticketNumber)
        analystNameString4.set(analystName)
        analystPhoneString4.set(analystNumber)
        ticketTitleString4.set(title)
        #Start Timer

    elif ticketNumberString5.get() != '':
        ticketNumberString5.set(ticketNumber)
        analystNameString5.set(analystName)
        analystPhoneString5.set(analystNumber)
        ticketTitleString5.set(title)
        #Start Timer
    else:
        print('Too Many Pages!')
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I understand that this is probably terrible to have so many copies of what is essentially the same code, but I'm still very much new to this and this is actually LESS repetitive than my first attempt at making this, which included 5 versions of every function.

Comment: Friend your code ugly . Try this :`dct = {}; a = 'q','w','e','r','t','y'` and `for e in a : dct[e]=None`, can change,delete etc. So don't need `StringVar()`