# Condensing python code for creating tkinter widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a program that I'm designing to teach myself Python but have gotten stuck. I've run across a way to condense python code using % and a list of arguments to have it run as code and looping through the list of arguments until it's done, but can't seem to find it in the documentation or with Google, mostly because I can't figure out how to search for it (sadly it's pretty vague I know).

Mostly what I'm trying to do is prevent having to write approx. 300 lines simply for GUI buttons, labels, frames, ect. with very few changes between them.

Obviously the code is huge so it's all available at Github, github.com/kari-fox/MixxMaster. I'm looking for any kind of recommendations for condensing all of the GUI elements, mostly because I find myself copy/pasting any time I need to make minor changes to any of the similar pieces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212354/making-changes-global-variables-from-within-a-function/38212707#38212707 i think more user angry me for **'Clean code is important !'** words.

Comment: Since you have at least 8 sections of code that are virtually the same just have differing text I would suggest creating a class to act as a template for each. You can then greatly reduce your code down.

Comment: Tip: Use [new string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of % formatting- it is as easy to understand as % (sometimes easier) and has way more features. Also it lets you use the same string multiple times without having to verbosely reference (i.e. `"{0} {1} {0}".format("foo", "bar")` == `"foo bar foo"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steven Summers in the comments for mentioning classes. I had no idea they were so powerful! I found this guide (https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) and it made understanding and implementing classes work perfectly! That helped me cut out almost 100 lines of purely window-building code and let me do a few sneaky things besides. If anyone wants to see the full implementation check out the github link in the question.